# How to watch multiple folders with nodemon?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemon

I need something like this:

nodemon.json:

```
[{
  "watch": ["src/api-gateway"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "ts-node ./src/api-gateway/main.ts"
},
{
  "watch": ["src/services/ping-service"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "ts-node ./src/services/ping-service/ping-service.ts"  
}]
```

Is that possible, or if there is some alternative way to do it?

Answer (score 7):

Use the array for watch option

```
"watch": [
    "folder1",
    "folder2",
]
```

You can look at the sample here https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md

Comment: But I need to run diffirent file depending on which folder is changed...

Comment: launch two different instances of nodemon, which will watch different folders